# Add mean value and n-number to nvd3 boxplot

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, boxplot

I am using nvd3 boxplot for my charts. Is there any option to have `mean` as an asterisk (*) on the boxplot? Can we also have the `n` value above the top whisker similar to the image below.

[image]

This issue has been posted [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1402).
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I would like to add a mean value which I calculate from the data points and not just the center of the box plot. The computed mean may not be in the center of the box plot due to outliers.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by doing the following algorithm:

1. Get all the rectangles
2. Find the middle point
3. Create a text and put it in the above calculated center

Code snippet:

```
function makeMarkOnMean(){
    d3.selectAll(".mean").remove();//remove all * mean markers
    //get all the rectangles
    d3.selectAll(".nv-boxplot-box")[0].forEach(function(r){
      window.setTimeout(function(){
        var x = parseFloat(d3.select(r).attr("x")) + d3.select(r).attr("width")/2 - 3; //x position of the star
        var y = parseFloat(d3.select(r).attr("y")) + parseFloat(d3.select(r).attr("height"))/2+12;//y position of the star
        //now make the star on the above x and y        
        d3.select(r.parentNode).append("text").attr("class", "mean").style("font-size", "x-large").text("*").style("fill", "red").attr("x",x).attr("y", y);
      },500)
});
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nIsoYm782uDW2Gqzh5Yt?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks. But sorry I was not clear in the question  - i would like to add the mean value calculated from the data points to the plot. Suppose I have calculated the means, I would like to place the asterisk in that appropriate place. Note that this may not be in the center of the box plot.

Comment: The calculated mean may not be the center due to the outliers. Let me know if I am clear..

Comment: For example, how to display mean of y=180, y=380, y=100 for the boxplots in the sample code you provided. If I just enter these values for mean, the points are not according to the scale of the plot.

Comment: See the x calculation will not change the y value will change which will place the star along the y axis. So its you biz logic how to calculate the mean y and place it there. to get the data on the box plot do `console.log(d3.select(r).data()[0]` changed the fiddle as well

Comment: Ok.. So should I use `d3.select(r).data(meanValue)[0]` where `meanValue` is the calculated mean? Can you please give the link to updated fiddle? Can you please help me place the calculated value on the boxplot. I am not so clear about it still.

Comment: No `d3.select(r).data(meanValue)[0]` this is wrong. I am saying that `d3.select(r).data()[0]` will give you the data on the boxplot ...See i dont know how to calculate the mean ...you will have to do that and with mean you should be able to calculate the y coordinate where to place the star the fiddle is here http://plnkr.co/edit/nIsoYm782uDW2Gqzh5Yt?p=preview

Comment: So I have the mean value calculated. How can I calculate the y coordinate where to place the star? Sorry but not sure how to do this and am unable to see any changes in your fiddle... I am unable to understand

Comment: :) the fiddle has just one change that its printing the data of teh box on the console..i am doing so that you may calculate the mean from there. I dont know what is outliner and how mean has to be calculted you need to do that...and find the corresponding position of y coordinate